# Excel Function to Concatenate & Exclude Zeros

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have concatenate pulling several cells names and then the value in those cells. For ex. `=Concatenate(“Dog:”&B4&”,”&”Cat:”&C4&”,”` etc…)but when referencing it if B4 is 0 then I just want it to display the value for Cat. How would I be able to do this ?

Comment: You got some great answers here.  Please include a before and after example of your data so we better understand exactly what you mean as there are a few ways to interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the following formula to include as many items as you wish:
*As per your tags, this assumes no Excel version constraints*

```
=TEXTJOIN(
    ",",
    TRUE,
    BYCOL(
        FILTER(VSTACK({"Dog:", "Cat:"}, B4:C4), B4:C4 <> 0),
        LAMBDA(arr, CONCAT(arr))
    )
)
```

- Using `VSTACK`, create a 2 column 2 row array consisting of the animal names, and the values in `B4:C4`

  - *Note you can add more animal names, and a larger range in row 4 if needed*
- Filter that array to exclude any column where there is a zero in the 2nd row.
- For each column in the filtered array, `CONCAT` the two cells
- For each concatenated cells, `TEXTJOIN` with a `comma` delimiter

As suggested by @BlindSpots, a more compact formula using a similar approach seems equally effective for this problem as presented:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER({"Dog: ","Cat: "} & B4:C4,B4:C4<>0))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @BlindSpots Tks. I'll revise after the OP clarifies.

Comment: @BlindSpots I added your suggestion with attribution. Thanks for the simplification.

Comment: @BlindSpots FYI, the argument, when blank, will return the "default value" for that argument. In the case of `TEXTJOIN`, the default is `TRUE`.  Some arguments in other functions also have defined default values. I note that Microsoft Help for the `TEXTJOIN` function does not list the default value -- possibly an oversight, or maybe not guaranteed to always behave this way in the future.  Your guess as to the reason for the absence of documentation is as good as mine.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a conditional `if` statement in this concat string.

Syntax is:
`IF(condition,value when true,value when false)`

[image: excel]

For what you are doing, if the value for "Cat" is in "C4" and you want that value to appear as "B4" if "B4" is zero then:

`=CONCAT("Dog:"&IF(B4=0,C4,B4)," Cat:"&C4)`

So, if `B4=0`, then we print the value of `C4` and if it has a value other than `0`, we print `B4`.

Answer (score 1):

### Formula

Only concatenate **`"Dog:"&B4`** with **`"Cat:"&C4`** , if **`B4`** is not  **`0`**   <sup><sub>***** *see note*</sub></sup>

```
=IF(B4<>0,"Dog:"&B4,"")&"Cat:"&C4
```

<sup>*****  *Excel will interpret an empty cell as equivalent to* **`0`**</sup>

### Explanation

1. Uses the [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function to return either `"Dog:"&B4` , or a blank string, based on the value in `B4` .
2. The value returned by the [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function is then concatenated with `"Cat:"&C4` .

###### IF Function

```
=IF(test,if_true,if_false) //  Syntax

=IF(B4=0,"","Dog:"&B4)     //  TEST: B4=0

=IF(B4<>0,"Dog:"&B4,"")    //  TEST: NOT(B4=0)
```

##### CONCAT, CONCATENATE,  &

1. [CONCAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) function replaced [CONCATENATE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) in Excel 2016.  Both are *currently* supported, for backward compatibility.
2. [CONCAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) joins a comma-separated list of values.
3. The [calculation operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a#:%7E:text=Text%20concatenation%20operator)  `&`  (ampersand character) can be used to concatenate instead of a function.

##### Concatenation Examples

```
=CONCAT("Dog","Cat","Bird")      // Function       

=CONCATENATE("Dog","Cat","Bird") // Function (deprecated)

="Dog"&"Cat"&"Bird"              // Operator

=CONCAT("Dog","Cat"&"Bird")      // Mixed
```